# Can't figure out how to get response JSON using remote: true in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-6

**UPDATE:**
I discovered that the issue was a library dependency issue. I didn't have `jquery-rails` gem installed therefore I wasn't requiring the `jquery-ujs` library in my application. In short, I was using `jquery-ujs` syntax when I only had the build in `rails-ujs` functionality available :( (face-palm). thanks for all who looked and provided and answer.

---

I feel I am doing something fairly basic, but for some reason I can't figure out what it is I am doing wrong. I am able to successfully create a record asynchronously with AJAX by using the `remote: true` option of the `form_for` helper. However, the simple JSON structure I am trying to return does not seem to be available in the `data` object of the AJAX response. When I run `console.log(data)` I get `undefined` in the browser js console.

here is a pretty accurate representation of my code:

form in view:

```
= form_for :thing, remote: true, html: { id: 'thing' } do |f|
      = f.text_field :name
      = f.submit 'submit'
```

my controller code:

```
def create
    @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)

    if @thing.save
      render json: { message: 'Thank you' }
    else
      render json: { message: 'oh no' } 
    end
end
```

my javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#thing').on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(data)
      }).on('ajax:error', function(e, xhr, status, error){
        console.log(error)
      });
})
```

I googled like crazy, and I am just at a loss. But maybe there is something really simple I am overlooking. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

Rails UJS defaults to sending remote requests with the
`application/javascript` content type.

If you want to request JSON you attach a `data-type="json"` attribute to the element:

```
= form_for @thing, remote: true, html: { id: 'thing' }, data: { type: "json" } do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.submit 'submit'
```

There is also the issue of Turbolinks. Your code attaches an event handler directly to the elements:

```
$('#thing').on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
  console.log(data)
};
```

While this will work on the initialial page load, it won't work when Turbolinks replaces the page contents with Ajax. Instead you need to create an [idempotent event handler](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent):

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '#thing', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
  console.log(data);
}).on('ajax:error', '#thing', function(e, xhr, status, error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

This attaches an event handler to the document itself that will catch the event as it bubbles up the DOM.
As such you don't need to wrap this code in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`.

You should also return meaningful HTTP response codes - thats what will determine if Rails UJS triggers `ajax:success` or `ajax:error`. Not JSON messages which are an anti-pattern.

```
def create
  @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)

  if @thing.save
    # Tell the client where the newly created object can be found
    head :created, location: @thing
    # or return a json representation of the object
    render json: @thing, status: :created
  else
    # just return a header 
    head :unprocessable_entity
    # or return a JSON object with the errors
    render json: { errors: @thing.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and great advice on returning the meaningful HTTP response codes. I actually discovered that the issue was a library dependency issue. I didn't have `jquery-rails` gem installed therefore I wasn't requiring the `jquery-ujs` library in my application. In short, I was using `jquery-ujs` syntax when I only had the build in `rails-ujs` functionality available.

Comment: How come the `console.log(error)` and `console.log(data)` both print out `undefined`